# What does ギョグ mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, onomatopoeia

In my dictionaries and on the Internet, the only meaning I found for ギョグ was "fishing gear", but in the context of the text I have been translating it does not make sense. The context is: two monsters and a boy fell to the ground.

> ガ　　ガア!?
>
> Thud, Thuud!!
>
> ふっ!
>
> Shoom!
>
> ギョグ!?
>
> Fishing gear!?

Comment: It's a kind of "creative" onomatopoeia. Maybe a surprise, a groan or a sound some creature makes.

Answer (score 2):

It, as well as ガア, shoud be just a screech of that monster. ギョグ is not common, but there is no rule on how imaginary monsters should cry.

Comment: I think it could be "Yelp" for a reaction of surprise and/or fear.